# jsdom: Cannot read property '_location' of null

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, jsdom

I'm getting test failed when I test epic via jest.

```
Test Failed
/.../node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:148

return idlUtils.wrapperForImpl(idlUtils.implForWrapper(window._document)._location);

TypeError: Cannot read property '_location' of null
    at Window.get location [as location] (/.../node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:148:79)
    at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (/.../node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:525:40)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:380:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:244:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

And this is some of my test. I used fetch() and promise in fetchCategoriesEpic.

```
it('test epic', () => {
    ...
    const action$ = ActionsObservable.of({ type: FETCH_CATEGORIES })

    fetchCategoriesEpic(action$)
      .toArray() // collects everything in an array until our epic completes
      .subscribe((actions) => {
        expect(actions).toEqual([
          { type: FETCH_CATEGORIES },
          { type: FETCH_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS, payload: List(payload.data).map((category) => new Category(category)) }
        ])
      })
    ...
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears this issues is really related to jsdom only, not redux-observable,
 so you may want to change your title, description, tags. You'll probably want to include any configuration/usage of jsdom in your tests and what node version you're using.

[Others have reported](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/search?q=Cannot+read+property+%27_location%27+of+null&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) similar issues in the past but no clear solution I can find with a quick Google search. My gut would tell me your configuration is slightly off and it doesn't realize it should create a fake location object for you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when attempting to use `document.documentElement` while testing in an environment where `document` was undefined.

I added a conditional to that part of application code and my tests ran fine after that.

Make sure your application code rather than your test code is attempting to accessing ONLY elements that exist in your test environment.